# When to use the xcolor package instead of the color package?

Tags: packages, color, best-practices

**Can someone explain when to use the `xcolor` package instead of the `color` package?**

Unless you are creating your own specific colors, the differences between the packages seem to be fairly superficial. Am I missing something that makes one package better than the other?

Note: I only use the packages to add a little bit of color here and there to my documents. I'm by no means an advanced user, but I want to know which of the packages are preferred and for what reasons.

Edit: The `xcolor` package documentation states: *Its purpose can be summarized as to maintain the characteristics of color, while providing additional features and flexibility with (hopefully) easy-to-use interfaces.*

So for non-advanced users, its just a matter of syntax preference, right?

Comment: I always use `xcolor` and I love (and probably over-use) `\colorlet{<new color name>}{<old color name>}` (e.g. for `\colorlet{important}{red}` or something)

Comment: The use of colour mixtures is a *big* addition brought along by [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) (e.g. using `\color{blue!30!green}`).

Comment: I think you answered your own question, if you don't need the additional features of `xcolor` you can simply stick with `color`; even though I can't see the disadvantage in using `xcolor` in the first place.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

All features of `color` are available by loading the `xcolor` package as well. I would say that you can always load the latter one since:

1. You don't have to care which features are in which one.
2. You surely satisfy all other packages relying on `color/xcolor`.
3. Many package load it anyways (`tikz` to name the most important one), so you even don't have to load it yourself.

Notice that there are other pairs of packages where one extends the other:

- `color` < `xcolor`
- `graphics` < `graphicx`
- `amsmath` < `mathtools` (in the sense you don't have to load `amsmath`)
- and surely more...

Comment: I would have one caveat regarding mathtools. it throughs our warning when using `unicode-math`. I sure one can get rid of these but haven't worked at how yet.

Comment: Not to forget: users of TikZ are loading `xcolor` anyway

Comment: @ArTourter I know (that's why I added the notice to that one). However, I included these comments only to provide some "background" ;)

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Sounds like I should always load `xcolor`. 

It sure would be nice to have a table or document for all of these kinds of "super" packages. Someone new (or a mid-level user, like myself) to LaTeX would unknowingly load a package not ever knowing the capabilities of the advanced packages.

Comment: @Jeremy If you open this page that exists for every package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/color you see that for package `color`, the package `xcolor` is listed under "See also".