# Latex compile errors with copernicus discussions template

Tags: errors, templates

I'm trying to compile a paper using the template for [Copernicus publishing](http://publications.copernicus.org/for_authors/latex_instructions.html). In particular, I'm trying to use the Ocean Science Discussion option.

Here is a code snippet:

```
\documentclass[osd, hvmath]{copernicus_discussions} %Ocean Science Discussion
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\title{title}
\author[1]{me}
\affil[1]{Institute}
\runningtitle{title}
\runningauthor{me}
\correspondence{me}

\firstpage{0}
\maketitle  
\begin{abstract}
a
\end{abstract}
\introduction 
blah blah blah
\conclusions  
conclude
\begin{thebibliography}{0}
\bibitem{label}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This is just a cleaned up version of the template given in the link above. But for some reason, I get a bunch of errors when I try to compile (with latex or pdflatex).

I can post the errors if it would help, but most say the error is on line 21 (i.e. `\end{document}`), and don't really seem (to me) to suggest what might be the problem.

I was wondering if anyone would mind trying to build that simple document to a pdf, using the class files in the link above. At least this would tell me if the problem is local to my machine (for eg. a missing package or something) or if it's a problem with the template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to insert a `\bibitem{label}` inside `thebibliography`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks texenthusias!
I added \bibtem{label}, and attempted to compile, but the same errors are thrown up. (I'll edit my post to show this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{xcolor}` after `\documentclass` and your source will compile.

```
\documentclass[osd, hvmath]{copernicus_discussions} %Ocean Science Discussion
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
...
```

Comment: and a quick note to the journal to ask them to update their class file would be a nice idea :)

Comment: Spot on @LostBrit. Thank you. I stumbled across this solution just then. I found adding `\usepackage{color}` to solve the problem. 
Is there a benefit to `xcolor` instead of `color`? Cheers!

Comment: Not sure. There's a discussion here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89763/when-to-use-the-xcolor-package-instead-of-the-color-package