# Using MikTeX how can we color some text

Tags: color, tcolorbox

I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 8.1. The PDF output of the Following TeX file does not display the word "example" in fore color or background color. I'm using TeXWorks editor - that comes with MikTeX - to generate the PDF:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is an {\color{green}example} of fore color text.
This is an \colorbox{green}{example} of highlighted text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
\usepackage{color}
```

to the preamble

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to send them straight to `xcolor`, or are there advantages of `color`?

Comment: @David, I followed your suggestion. Now, I'm getting the following error: "The required file tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii is missing. It is a part of the following package: mptopdf". I thought the MikTeX would include the color package by default. It does display all my amsmath correctly without installing any extra packages.

Comment: MiKTeX includes perhaps `xolor` by default, but it is not part of base LaTeX, so that you have to load it. Also you should load `xcolor`rather than color, as @Steven B. Segletes commented.

Comment: @nam You can also write the text colour as `\textcolor{green}{hello}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes personally I'd use color:-)

Comment: @nam no you need `\usepackage{amsmath}` to use the ams math environments (or a class that does that, such as `amsart`) It is not loaded by default.

Comment: @nam you (apparently) need to use the miktex package manager to install `mptopdf` which seems strange, did you do a minimal initial installation?

Comment: After I installed mptopdf package (size: 153202 bytes), the David's suggestion worked. I used this package over xcolor (size: 968805 bytes) because of the size difference between the two. xcolor probably has extra functionality available that I don't need. xcolor was not installed by default either.

Comment: @David, I did do the minimal initial installation (if I recall correctly). It's working with the amsmath without using `\usepackage{amsmath}`. I also checked in the miktex package manager that amsmath package was among the installed packages and it's installation date shows as the date when I installed the MikTex. I installed MikTeX on Jan 4, 2015.

Comment: @David, You are absolutely correct. While the following works without `\usepackage{amsmath}`:  `\begin{eqnarray}
x^2 + y^2 &=& 1
\\ y &=& \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
\end{eqnarray}` The following gives an error (if not using the \usepackage{amsmath} in the preamble)  as: "LaTeX Error: Environment align* undefined":
`\begin{eqnarray}
x^2 + y^2 &= 1
\\ y &= \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
\end{eqnarray}`.

Comment: `eqnarray` is in the latex format (and shouldn't be used) you should use `amsmath` environments instead. @nam

Comment: I think you're very biased in your preference for `color`, David :-) `xcolor` is just... plain better. @nam, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89763/17423. Also, if you don't have `xcolor` installed by default, you likely chose a very minimal installation with automatic package installation. I guarantee you will have problems if you continue to use TeX like this.

Comment: @SeanAllred yes sure but (a) you should let a bloke use his own packages and (b) for the example in the question, `color` is all you need, and is guaranteed to be in any LaTeX installation.

Comment: (a) :-) (b) Very true, but it's often better to Keep Things Simple (tm) by loading more encompassing packages. I would at least note in the answer that `xcolor` is preferred when available (and very often loaded by other packages anyway) even if `color` is all that's required here. Your answer is correct, it's just not good for beginners, in my honest opinion :)

Comment: I think @SeanAllred missed the humor in your comment about `color` over `xcolor`.  If the package developer doesn't stand up for his own package, who will?  It's why I put up with abuse for stacking things that are traditionally done via the `amsmath` environments.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes oh no I understand :) I'm just advising OP who may not know any better :) and by the way, those answers of yours prove just how versatile your stack engine is :) there's nothing wrong with promoting your own package, it just makes sense to eventually give a newbie all the information :)

Comment: @SeanAllred although in this case I'm not sure I agree, color is the standard in the same way article is. In both cases there are better more fully featured alternatives, but for a beginner starting with the version that appears in tutorials and the official latex manual is surely not bad advice. (Apart from which I've not personally used xcolor (although I've read its code a couple of times) so I'd have to look up any syntax examples that were not the same as color. (same comments to whoever downvoted if that isn't you:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wouldn't downvote an answer that works :) in that sense, I would agree with you. I suppose I just wish there were well-known resources for 'second phase' learners of TeX and friends – if not, I suppose I'll just have to write one :)